# Send custom email template for different product - woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress website using woocommerce plugin.I have different kinds of products and i need to send different email template for different products.

I found the only solution is to add checking on each template files for email in `woocommerce/emails` in theme folder .is there any better method for doing this?

Is there any option available in

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email', 'woocommerce_email_function' );
```

OR

Is it possible to add different header for order for a particular product?

Comment: As you know there is 2 ways: 1) Use [all available hooks](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html) related to email notifications (some of them are located in the templates themselves). 2) [Override woocommerce templates via the theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) … As your question is not very detailed (we can't guess what you are trying to do) and you don't show your custom code, is not really possible to answer this question…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have different products in my store.if order placed,there will be sending order emails using the templates.i need to use different template based on product id

Comment: Yes I have understood that before thanks… Which code and where… can you provide the code that you are using in this overrided templates? ... Thanks

Comment: @LoicTheAztec That is not written yet.The method i planed to code is,to check with order id in template file ,and if it is an order with the productid,then return html for the template

Comment: OK but the answer depend on the location where you want to display your html code (and for what order status ?) So please can you add the code you want to add and the exact location (when conditions are matched)… this way I would be able to help…

Comment: Have you tried my solution below?

Answer (score 1):

I had a heck of a time figuring out how to get the order ID from `'woocommerce_email'`, and couldn't find an answer on StackOverflow so I thought I might share what worked for me.

Overriding templates is the most obvious way to change email content, but it was messing up email templates from other plugins, like Smart Coupons.

I was able to remove the email_order_details.php template programmatically from emails containing a specific product like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email', 'remove_woocommerce_email_order_details' );

// Using $object in function was key to remove_action below
function remove_woocommerce_email_order_details( $object ) {

    // Simple way to get the order ID
    $order_id = get_the_ID();

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

        // If product ID in order, remove order details
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        if ( $product_id == 1234 ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', array( $object, 'order_details' ), 10, 4 );
        } 
    }

}
```

Now I added the `woocommerce_email_order_details` table back with my own data.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'add_custom_email_order_details' );

function add_custom_email_order_details() {

    // With these, you should be able access most elements in the 'woocommerce_email_order_details' table
    $order_id = get_the_ID();
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $order_type = $order->order_type;
    $customer_id = $order->get_user_id();

    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    }

    if( $product_id == 1234 ) {
        echo "Order Type: " . $order_type;
        echo "Customer ID: " . $customer_id;
        echo "Product ID:" . $product_id;
    }

}
```

Hope that helps someone else!

Comment: Turns out this solution was only working for emails triggered manually from the Edit Order page. So it would work correctly on new orders, I moved `remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', array( $object, 'order_details' ), 10, 4 );` from the `remove_woocommerce_email_order_details` function to the `add_custom_email_order_details` function, right after `if( $product_id == 1234 )`

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, for example for the product ID `999` you want to display the header title `This is a very special title`:

```
function change_email_title_header_depending_of_product_id( $email_heading, $order ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $order->get_items();

    // check products
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        if ( $product_id == 999 ) {
            $email_heading = 'This is a very special title';
        }
        return $email_heading;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_heading_customer_processing_order', 'change_email_title_header_depending_of_product_id', 10, 2 );
```